# Rails4 - How to add custom data attributes to body tag in ActiveAdmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

I am using activeadmin gem in my Rails4 app and just wondering how i can add custom attributes on my `body` tag or **custom meta tag** in my markup.There are few approaches :-

1. **Override** the `layout` and easily define `helper`/function to get the meta tag/body custom attributes.
2. Keep the default settings, just **include** custom js file in `initializers/active_admin.js` and let the js make an ajax call and make changes in the body tag and add some attributes.
3. **Is there any other way..an easy one?**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend against overriding layout.  With the latest version in GitHub you can override ActiveAdmin::Views::Pages::Base#add_classes_to_body, and #build_active_admin_head for meta tags, but I don't recommend that either.  ActiveAdmin adds selectors to body for the action and controller as well as the namespace and whether logged in, what more do you need?

Comment: thanks i am aware of it but what if that changes...as the logic will be heavily dependent on it..

Comment: My best guess is that the way the attributes are added is more likely to be changed (internal refactor) than the attributes themselves (public interface).